# Javascript OO Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need something obvious pointing out to me in regard to JS functions.

The following code works, but I want to call upon it anywhere:

```
var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/;
var date = entry.date.split(' ');
var date = date[0];
var date = new Date(date.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));
var year = date.getYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
```

What would be the best practice to place this in a global function so I can just do `adjustDate(string)`. Double points (Sadly, not in my power) to explain how I would then also have access to all the objects such as `year`, `month`, `day`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of this? I mean, which parts do you need to access after this is processed? The `date` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just return a `date` without abstracting its existing methods

```
function AdjustedDate(dateString)
{
    return new Date(dateString.split(' ')[0].replace(/(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1'));
}

var ad = AdjustedDate(entry.date);

alert(ad);
alert(ad.getDay());
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just declare the function?

```
function adjustDate(entry) {
    var date = entry.date.split(' ');
    date = date[0];
    date = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1'));

    return {
        year: date.getYear(),
        month: date.getMonth(),
        day: date.getDay()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the entry into the function and then pass an object containing the information you want out. Then just access it like you would an ordinary JS object.

```
function adjustDate(entry) {
  var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/;
  var date = entry.date.split(' ');
  var date = date[0];
  var date = new Date(date.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));
  var year = date.getYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var day = date.getDay();
  return { day: day, month: month, year: year }
}

var dateObject = adjustDate(/*entry*/)

dateObject.day // day
dateObject.month // month
```